# Expected number of days inside a corridor

Tags: monte-carlo, random-walk, random-variables

Is there a simple (ish) approximation for the expected number of steps a random walk is within a set of bounds over a given time period? - in particular if i presume log normal and constant vol.

If i want to do it with something like local/stochastic/both vol, then is there a way to do it without resorting to MC/diffusion?

Comment: Can you remind us what is the payoff of a corridor?

Comment: The way I interpret this is the Stopping Time $\tau$ until $x(\tau) \geq B1 ∨ x(\tau) \leq B2$

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer - it's the total number of days it is within the corridor, it does not knock out.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like a range accrual. Let $t_1, \ldots, t_n$, where $0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n$ be business days that are being considered. We compute
\begin{align*}
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \pmb{1}_{b_1 < S_{t_i} < b_2} \right) &=\sum_{i=1}^n E\left(\pmb{1}_{b_1 < S_{t_i} < b_2} \right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left[E\big(\pmb{1}_{S_{t_i} > b_1}\big) -E\big(\pmb{1}_{S_{t_i} \ge b_2} \big) \right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\Phi\big(d_2^i(b_1)\big) - \Phi\big(d_2^i(b_2)\big)\right],
\end{align*}
where, for positive constant $K$,
\begin{align*}
d_2^i(K) = \frac{\ln\frac{S_0}{K} + \big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \big) t_i}{\sigma \sqrt{t_i}}.
\end{align*}
For general stochastic volatility, there is no simple method. Monte Carlo may be needed.

Comment: Okay, I thought was afraid MC might have been the only way.

Comment: For the constant vol version though, this is presuming that each possible accrual day is a completely unrelated event to the say before, which is completely not the case, it's path dependant.

Comment: @will: Yes, unless you have a dterministic volatility function.

Comment: presumably only a subset of deterministic vol functions are solvable in and simple (ish) way.

Comment: For a path-dependent version, you may need to define the structure more specifically. The version given is only my own speculation.

Comment: ,as in if it's out of the range on day i, then it's likely to be out on i+1.

Comment: If you can write out the dependence in a mthematical form, it may be helpful.

Comment: I don't have it, it was more a general question. But I don't think it's as simple as in your answer, since $S_i$ is correlated with $S_j$.

Comment: They are indeed correlated, but the number of steps is a sum, and the expectation is additive, unless you can define your understanding of  expected number of steps more specifically, my answer is what I can interpret.